# Como configurar um Servidor de Autenticação e Autorização?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, authorization

Como configurar um servidor de autenticação e autorização como o Google, por Cookie, e então poder disponibilizar para aplicações ASP.NET MVC de um mesmo grupo de aplicações web com mesma base de usuários?

Estive tentando entender **[esse exemplo](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)**, que porém utiliza o Google, para tentar identificar uma forma de criar tal configuração.
Mas não entendi como poderia fazer minha própria validação e também retornar os dados do usuário (Propriedades, Roles e Claims).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alguém já fez este trabalho por você](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), com mais recursos que o link de exemplo.

[Veja os passos de configuração aqui](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/overview.html).